# Suspend/ Resume in android

Tags: android, c, device-driver

I am trying to develop a driver which has registered with a GPIO interrupt in android. Here i need to wakeup the device via the GPIO interrupt. i have registered my suspend/resume callback with the device driver PM structure in my driver. my code snippet is

```
static int my_suspend(struct device *dev)
{
    struct i2c_client *client = to_i2c_client(dev);
    disable_irq(client->irq);
    if (device_may_wakeup(&client->dev)) 
    enable_irq_wake(client->irq);
    return 0;
}

static int my_resume(struct device *dev)
{
    struct i2c_client *client = to_i2c_client(dev);
    if (device_may_wakeup(&client->dev))
    disable_irq_wake(client->irq);
    enable_irq(client->irq);
    return 0;
}

static const struct dev_pm_ops i2c_pm_ops = {
    .suspend    = my_suspend,
    .resume     = my_resume,
};

struct device_driver lcd_driver = {
    ....
    .pm = &i2c_pm_ops,
    ....
}
```

But my suspend function is not called while system suspend action.

Comment: So, did you write a complete driver with `open()` `read()` `write()` `close()` ? You need to compile `.ko` then load it by `insmod`

Comment: Yes i had compiled and checked it in a qualcomm chipset. All are working fine but this suspend and resume...